# How to decompress the gzip response in Karate

Tags: karate

Is there any way to decompress the gzip response with Karate?. I have tried with karate-apache v0.9.6 and karate-jersey v0.9.6, but both did not decompress the response content by default.
When I try to fetch and print the response, I see like this.

```
INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] the resp   l�ǒ�@�Ee�{��wh�5�Bk-�����ͪ͘�T
```

I am not sure what is that I am missing here.

But when I tried with apache httpclient.GzipDecompressingEntity, I managed to decompress the response entity to string and works as expected.
`final String s1 = IOUtils.toString(gzipDecompressingEntity.getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

I have also referred [this](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1229) issue, but no luck.

This is the karate output:

**with Jersey**

```
1 > GET http://localhost:4000/somedata?type=json&gzip=yes
1 > Accept-Encoding: deflate
1 > User-Agent: Jersey/2.30 (HttpUrlConnection 11.0.9)

[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 139.51
1 < 200
1 < Cache-control: no-cache
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somedata.gz"
1 < Content-Length: 78056
1 < Content-Type: application/gzip
1 < Keep-Alive: timeout=5

[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] the resp       
l�ǒ�@�Ee�{��wh�5�Bk-�����ͪ͘�T   �~�Ɋ�iʴ(�?������巵us���a,�]n^�jz=a�gU��!
```

**with Apache Httpclient**

```
1 > GET http://localhost:4000/somedata?type=json&gzip=yes
1 > Accept-Encoding: deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11.0.9)

17:26:14.243 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 102.86
1 < 200
1 < Cache-control: no-cache
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somedata.gz"
1 < Content-Length: 78065
1 < Content-Type: application/gzip
1 < Keep-Alive: timeout=5

 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] the resp       
��(K�hP���J��G�w�nQG=i�U�(g�=�p���0�3`_����To�3�A��Բ�m�
```

Can someone advise me here, please? Thanks!

Comment: @PeterThomas, Thanks for reminding, I have marked the answers to the previous questions as accepted.  Also I am not that familiar with process on Stackoverflow.

Please advise if there is anyway to decompress the gzip response with Karate.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an enhancement request for Karate.

If you have some ideas of code changes, please submit a PR just like the person who submitted the issue linked did. At the very least, please submit a way to replicate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Of course, before that can you check if the 1.0 RC release solves this - because the HTTP client was re-factored a little: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

EDIT - OP has provided an answer in the comments which I am adding below. Since Karate exposes the raw bytes of every response as [a variable called `responseBytes`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#responsebytes) you can use a custom Java utility to convert:

```
byte[] bytes=(byte[]) responseBytes; //responseBytes object from Karate.
final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); //transform into ByteArrayInputstream
GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream); //Convert gzipInputstream
final String decompressedOutput = IOUtils.toString(gzipInputStream,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. Let me try with the v1.0RC and check if it works, otherwise I will submit an issue.

Comment: Hello @PeterThomas, i just tested with v0.9.9RC4, it did not work and got the same garbled response. I have to create an example project before I log an issue.. Thank you again.
Also was wondering is there anyway I can collect the http entity response sent by karate and send it to java for any processing..

Comment: @sanm yes, the raw bytes will be available in `responseBytes`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#responsebytes - so you can pass that to a custom Java method. one of the things I am considering is to add a `karate.unzip()` method

Comment: I wanted to share a workaround [an interim solution] which may help others:

`byte[] bytes=(byte[]) responseBytes; //responseBytes object from Karate.
final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); //transform into ByteArrayInputstream
GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream); //Convert gzipInputstream
final String decompressedOutput = IOUtils.toString(gzipInputStream,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
`

Comment: @sanm awesome, I updated my answer to include your comment